# What is the best way to register existing Windows service in .NET?

Tags: .net, service

I need to register an existing third-party executable (database engine) Windows service from a .NET application. Is there a better way than writing to the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CodeProject item might be of interest, it gives some nice code and explains how to use installutil.exe from an installer (MSI) or from within your .net code.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynWinServiceInstallUtil.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[`installutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a better choice than manually writing to the registry, if that's what you're asking. If you're looking to do it programatically (through, say, a custom install action in an MSI), you may be able to use classes in the [System.Configuration.Install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install%28VS.80%29.aspx) namespace, specifically [AssemblyInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.assemblyinstaller%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could also wrap the [sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) command line tool.